# A "Brigadoon" But in the Appalachian Mountains?

Tags: myth-identification, folklore

The other day I was speaking to a friend, about Brigadoon. I seem to faintly remember there is folklore, about a town in Appalachia that did the same thing. It would disappear and reappear. But I've been unable to find anything. Has anyone heard of anything like this? It's also possible, that it was a Native-American folklore as well.